# Kde plasma freezes unexpectedly

Tags: kde, kubuntu, kde5

I have Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Last few weeks KDE started to 'freeze' occasionally. Is this a known issue? Is there any way how I can gracefully close/restart just the UI from terminal?
But most important, what should I check to collect some usefull logs or details that could help to determine the cause of the problem?

Detailed description:
KDE just gets stuck and I can not do anything in the graphical UI. It seems that this usually happens when i switch desktops or even windows on the same desktop (but I cannot reproduce). I can move the mouse cursor, the music is still playing in the background (clementine - and I can control it via keyboards shortcuts), I can log in to the console using Ctrl+Alt+F1, I can log in via SSH... But I can not control KDE anymore - I can not move windows, switches desktops, close windows, opening apps or anyting similar. Once this happened during skype call and the call was not interrupted and i was able to communicate.
This started to happen only few weeks ago, it hasn't been happening before. I haven't installed any new hardware lately.

Technical details that might be relevant:

```
root:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS \n \l

root:~# uname -a
Linux ryzen 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root:~#
root:~# kf5-config --version
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Qt: 5.15.3
KDE Frameworks: 5.92.0
kf5-config: 1.0
root:~#
root:~# lshw -c display
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: c5
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
resources: irq:144 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd7ffff memory:c0000-dffff
root:~#
root:~# lshw -c processor
*-cpu
description: CPU
product: AMD Ryzen 9 3950X 16-Core Processor
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
physical id: 11
bus info: cpu@0
version: 23.113.0
serial: Unknown
slot: AM4
size: 2199MHz
capacity: 4761MHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 100MHz
capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pc
lmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate
ssbd mba ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale
vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca sev sev_es cpufreq
configuration: cores=16 enabledcores=16 microcode=141561889 threads=32

root:~# lsmod | grep -i amd
edac_mce_amd 36864 0
kvm_amd 167936 0
kvm 1130496 1 kvm_amd
ccp 110592 1 kvm_amd
amdgpu 11300864 170
iommu_v2 24576 1 amdgpu
gpu_sched 49152 1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper 16384 1 amdgpu
ttm 98304 2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
drm_display_helper 184320 1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper 200704 4 drm_display_helper,amdgpu
drm 581632 22 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,amdgpu ,drm_ttm_helper,ttm
i2c_algo_bit 16384 2 igb,amdgpu
```

I have 128GB of memory overclocked to 3600MHZ (but i have it like this for 3 years without an issue). Also memtest seems ok (memtester 1G 10).

Thanks for any advice

​

Comment: Have you checked the logs in `/var/log`, like `syslog` or `messages`? Does `journalctl` show anything helpful? It'd be a good idea to upload those to for example Pastebin and [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738514/edit) the question to add links.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. But the thing is i don't know what to look for. In those logs (also in Xorg.0.log) I haven't found anything special. 
Some errors are there but only from the time after the KDE froze (I tired to run startd kdeplasma with few errors, so that's probably it). 
Anyway, here are few logs: 
https://pastebin.com/0SPUD2wH 
https://pastebin.com/w9QPnDgr 
https://pastebin.com/v3nTzzeJ

Comment: Whatever is there can be helpful. I'm sure I wouldn't know either what to look for, I've never used KDE; currently I waste no resources for any desktop managers :-) I troubleshoot with just CLI tools like `less` and `grep`, stripping off everything that looks normal. For example trying to troubleshoot KDE I'd filter out anything related to networking just to make the log more manageable size. Usually one can find something worth googling :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar Problem, KDE 5.X on Debian Trixie.
In my case as workaround helps switching to terminal session (for example Ctrl+Alt+F3 with no need to log-in ) and back again to GUI session Ctrl+Alt+whatever- number-is-GUI-session.The session appears to continue normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on Kubuntu 22.04.

As for now, I've upgraded MESA to 23.1 using [Oibaf's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).

Please see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463211/kwin-becomes-unresponsive-need-to-restart-session/1508451#1508451).

The upgraded drivers partially solve my problem. 
I could run KDE for ~1 day straight without the bug occurring,
but it still hangs approximately once per day.